# Editable console listview in python

Tags: python, listview, terminal, console

I'm trying to find a way to make an editable listview in python to be used in a terminal.

Basically each line of that listview will have a single word and I would like to be able to check or uncheck some words in the listview. Then, once I'm done editing I want to be able to close the listview and continue the rest of the program. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The curses library is a good way to do this. It allows you to write strings to the screen in a specific position instead of just constantly scrolling down like a typical Python program. And it has the ability to grab key  inputs so you could use arrow keys and space bar to select individual lines.

Because you can write strings to a specific position on the screen you can use a string like '[ ]' to represent an unselected option and '[*]' to represent a selected option. So when a user hits space you can toggle the current lines' selection status.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#the-python-curses-module

Comment: Thanks, that api looks interesting. It might really be what I'm looking for, now I just need to spend a few days studying it to be able to build what I want.